# Neo4j cypher getting nodes that are related to another node using ALL relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am doing a PoC to find out if a graph database will fit our needs.

We have a survey in which respondents have answered questions. We want to group these respondents using every possible combination of answers out of a set of (mostly two or three) questions.

I have the following nodes and relationships

```
(:Question)-[:HasAnswer]->(:Answer)
(:Respondent)-[:Answered]->(:Answer)
(:Answer)-[:BelongsTo]->(:WeightingGroup)
```

In which:

- Question: the question
- Answer: A possible answer to a question
- Respondent: A person that answered questions
- Answered: The relation between a respondent that answered a question
- WeightingGroup: A group of answers that form unique combinations of given answers
- BelongsTo: The relationship between an answer and a weightinggroup to form groups of answers.

My goal is to receive a result like this:

```
/----------------------------------------------\
| Q1                 | Q2                 | n  |
|--------------------+-------------------------|
| Answer1            | Answer1            | 23 | 
| Answer1            | Answer2            | 12 | 
| Answer1            | Answer3            | 54 | 
| Answer2            | Answer1            | 65 | 
| Answer2            | Answer1            |  5 | 
| Answer2            | Answer1            | 15 | 
\--------------------+--------------------+----/
```

or:

```
/-------------------------\
| Q1, Q2             | n  |
|--------------------+----|
| Answer1, Answer2   | 23 | 
| Answer1, Answer2   | 12 | 
| Answer1, Answer3   | 54 | 
| Answer2, Answer1   | 65 | 
| Answer2, Answer1   |  5 | 
| Answer2, Answer1   | 15 | 
\--------------------+----/
```

Where n is the number of respondents that gave both answers.

However, when I run this query:

```
// Aantal antwoorden per wegingsgroep
match (w:WeightingGroup)-[]->(a:Answer)<-[:Answered]-(r:Respondent)
with w, collect(distinct a.Text) as answers, count(distinct r) as n
return answers, w.Weight, n
```

It seems to be returning n = the number of respondents that answered answer1 OR answer2.

How do get the count of Respondents that gave answer1 AND answer2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly just add "WHERE length(answers) > 1" clause to your query.

Comment: please put a small sample dataset on http://console.neo4j.org and share it

Comment: I am working on a sample dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this: collect answers per group, collect answers per respondent, filter on where all answers for a respondent are present in the answers for a group. I think then the count on respondent should be ok (you'll have to extract the answer texts since the answers are already collected.)

```
MATCH (g:WeightingGroup)<-[:BelongsTo]-(a)
WITH g, collect(a) as apg
MATCH (r:Respondent)-[:Answered]->(a)
WITH g, apg, r, collect(a) as apr
WHERE ALL(a IN apr WHERE a IN apg)
RETURN g.Weight, EXTRACT(a IN apg | a.Text), count(r) as n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And sorry for the late response (carnaval came in between ;))

I tried this query but it crashed neo4J (taking all CPU and 2GB memory). This probably has to do with the fact that the database contains over 600.000 given answers.

Comment: Is that 600k possible answers across your questions, and every combination of them is an answer group? I think the query works but you may need to restructure the data or do the analysis in steps.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 6,000,000 given answers. I tried your query on a sample dataset and it did give me the desired results so will mark it as accepted answer :)

My Neo4j community however now refuses to start at all so I guess I seriously broke something :(